# save function does not work

Tags: magento-1.8

\app\code\local\Svi\Form\controllers\IndexController.php

```
<?php
Class Svi_Form_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function indexAction(){
        $layout =$this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function postAction()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $model = Mage::getModel('form/form')->setData($data);
        try {
            $insertId = $model->save()->getId();
            echo "Data successfully inserted. Insert ID: ".$insertId;
        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

}
?>
```

**From $model, I found following array......**

> Svi_Form_Model_Form Object ( [_eventPrefix:protected] => core_abstract
>   [_eventObject:protected] => object [_resourceName:protected] =>
>   form/form [_resource:protected] => [_resourceCollectionName:protected]
>   => form/form_collection [_cacheTag:protected] => [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1 [_isObjectNew:protected] =>
>   [_data:protected] => Array ( [fname] => amit [lname] => kushwaha
>   [mothername] => Sushma [fathername] => bholaNath [mobile] =>
>   8858234949 ) [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1 [_origData:protected] =>
>   [_idFieldName:protected] => [_isDeleted:protected] =>
>   [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array ( ) [_syncFieldsMap:protected] =>
>   Array ( ) )

I found my table blank but it gave me message 'successful inserted'. What to do? please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Replace this

```
 $insertId = $model->save()->getId();
```

with this

```
 $model->save();
 $insertId =  $model->getId();
```